# r exporting summarise results to html or word

Tags: r

After going to find how to summarize a DataFrame I did it.

I can see the results in my Console which is what is shown below after the first two lines of code

```
byTue <- group_by(luckyloss.3,L_byUXR)
( sumMon <- summarize(byTue,count=n()) )
```

Below is what I see on the Console  It feels good because it shows I got what I was looking for

The results below come from a column of 234 rows which has many values repeated.
So this I did a summarise  of the 234 rows where in the case of ANA comes 8 times, ARI 14 and so on

```
# A tibble: 30 × 2
   L_byUXR count
     <chr> <int>
1      ANA     8
2      ARI    14
3      ATL    16
4      BAL     4
5      BOS     6
6      CHA    12
7      CHN     8
8      CIN    10
9      CLE     4
10     COL     8
# ... with 20 more rows
```

What I want is to have this output of 30 rows by two columns in a way I can take it to a word document or could even be HTML

I tried to do a `write(byTUE.csv)` but what I received was the list of 234 rows of the original data frame. It's like the summarise disappeared, I have checked other ways like markdown or create new files tried to see if the knitr package could help but nothing.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(stringi) # ONLY NECESSARY FOR DATA SIMULATION
library(officer) # <<= install this
library(tidyverse)
```

Simulate some data:

```
set.seed(2017-11-18)
data_frame(
  L_byUXR = stri_rand_strings(30, 3, pattern="[A-Z]"),
  count = sample(20, 30, replace=TRUE)
) -> sumMon
```

Start a new Word doc and add the table, saving to a new doc:

```
read_docx() %>%  # a new, empty document
  body_add_table(sumMon, style = "table_template") %>% 
  print(target="new.docx")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there    I appreciate your answer and I'm happy to know that it can be done, although I couldn't according to your instructions   I already spent a lot of time here trying to follow your sample and nothing I  even went to the Officer package vignette where I can't even do their first instruction because I get an error.   What you showed me was that there are packages that can do what I need,Thanks again  Javier

Comment: if my example didn't work, there's something terribly amiss with your R installation.

Comment: You might be right. I had a lot of trouble installing officer and tidyverse too

Comment: Maybe if you could detail a little more I could get it, because you made it work. These are your instructions       1)read_docx() %>%  # a new, empty document  Question: Do I just write "read_docx() , do I put anything inside the parenthesis ?
  2) body_add_table(sumMon, style = "table_template") %>% 
  3) print(target="new.docx")  When you write "target="new.docx"  is this a file that should already exist in one of my session's folder ?

Answer (score 0):

I kept looking for an answer and found the "stargazer" package for R, which allowed me to get the result of the dataframe as a text which can be further edited

When you write the R instruction, in "out = ", name the file you want as output and stargazer will place it there for you in your session's folder

The instruction I used was:

```
    stargazer(count, type = "text", summary = FALSE, title="Any Title", digits=1, out="table1.txt")
```

Even though I found the answer I could not have done it without the help of hrbrmstr who showed me there was a package do do it, I just needed to work more on it